# Emphasize text that is highlighted using the soul package

Tags: highlighting, soul, emphasis

I can highlight a bit of text (i.e., make the background yellow) using the `soul` package like this:

```
\hl{a bit of text}
```

I figured I could also use italics like this:

```
\hl{\emph{a bit of text}}
```

... but it doesn't seem to work --- the text is still "normal". What am I missing?

Comment: I get italic text for the second example. Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? (Non working, in your case.)

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, it was an embarrassing mistake, which I've easily detected when I trying to build the minimal example. Thank you.

Comment: No need to be embarrassed! ;-) Preparing a MWE often points out a mistake that can go unobserved in a bigger document.